# How to convert a specific string to DateTime?

Tags: c#, string, datetime, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a string in this format:

```
Tuesday, Sep 01, 2020 04:15
Thursday, Aug 27, 2020 03:56
Friday, Aug 28, 2020 07:30
Tuesday, Aug 04, 2020 08:00
```

```cs
[Route("/test")]
public async void TestParseTime()
{
    string pattern = "dddd, MMM dd, YYYY HH:MM";
    string newsTimeString = "Thursday, Aug 27, 2020 03:56";
    DateTime newsTime = DateTime.ParseExact(newsTimeString, pattern, null);
    Console.WriteLine("newsTime = " + newsTime);
}
```

But the parsing of the string to datetime fails with the following exception:

[image]

How to convert it to a `DateTime` in C#?

Comment: Are you sure you mean HH:MM (considering uppercase M is month)? Also, if "Aug 1" is possible, you should use `MMM d` instead of `MMM dd` as that will cover "Aug 27" and "Aug 1".

Comment: I tend minute...

Comment: "HH:mm" not "HH:MM", John is absolutely correct.

Comment: Yes, capital "MM" at the end of the format string you might have used for minutes but "MM" is for the month and lower case "mm" is for minutes. So you need to use string pattern = "dddd, MMM dd, YYYY HH:mm"; hope it should sovle the problem

Comment: not work. https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1328316/91825572-a35fb800-ec66-11ea-8a98-e76e2c9ec804.png

Comment: Also small "y"s : https://dotnetfiddle.net/fapKUz Small tipp: If I run into Date-Parsing problems, I have a date be formatted by the pattern. That's quite quick to reveal some mishap.

Comment: Questions about how to parse and/or format strings as datetime are really in the millions. It seem obvious but still I suggest you to start from the docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#:~:text=A%20standard%20date%20and%20time%20format%20string%20uses,see%20Custom%20date%20and%20time%20format%20strings%20.

Comment: @Fildor even I copy text-by-text, still error https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1328316/91825940-21bc5a00-ec67-11ea-9573-177a76b8cd1b.png this is console log https://gist.github.com/donhuvy/313b0f29ac2b311552f8297750956ff0

Comment: @DoNhuVy have you tried `DateTime.Parse`? You just accepted the answer that simply calls `DateTime.Parse`

Comment: could you please post the Exception message also as text and not only as image. Iamges cannot be scanned by crawlers and neither be read by software to people whose sight is impaired

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to use the powerfull [Convert.ToDateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todatetime?view=netcore-3.1#System_Convert_ToDateTime_System_String_) method and simply feed the input in there:

```
string newsTimeString = "Thursday, Aug 27, 2020 03:56";
DateTime newsTime = Convert.ToDateTime(newsTimeString);
Console.WriteLine("newsTime = " + newsTime);
```

Output:

> newsTime = 27.08.2020 03:56:00

Actually the "Thursday" string is superfluous information for the `DateTime` object. Because it will know the day of week from the calendar. You can print it via the property:

```
Console.WriteLine("Day = " + newsTime.DayOfWeek);
```

Output:

> Day = Thursday

EDIT:

Apparently: "Convert.ToDateTime is just a [call to DateTime.Parse](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,1724)" (comment by Panagiotis Kanavos) So in this case you can also use:

```
DateTime newsTime = DateTime.Parse(newsTimeString);
```

and get the same result, without specifying any format.

Disclaimer:

From the Remarks section of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todatetime?view=netcore-3.1#System_Convert_ToDateTime_System_String_):

> "If value is not null, the return value is the result of invoking the
>  DateTime.Parse method on value using the formatting information in a
>  DateTimeFormatInfo object that is initialized for the current culture." -

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime` is [just a call to `DateTime.Parse`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,1724).

Comment: _"If value is not null, the return value is the result of invoking the DateTime.Parse method on value using the formatting information in a DateTimeFormatInfo object that is initialized **for the current culture**."_ - emphasis by me. Just one thing to be aware of, when using Convert.

Comment: @Fildor incorporated this also, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is incorrect. patterns are case-sensitive. Use this pattern instead:

dddd, MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm

```
string pattern = "dddd, MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm";
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString(pattern));

string newsTimeString = "Thursday, Aug 27, 2020 03:56";
DateTime newsTime = DateTime.ParseExact(newsTimeString, pattern, null);
Console.WriteLine("newsTime = " + newsTime);
```

Comment: It's 24-Hour, though "HH".

Comment: Well, his sample code uses 03:56 which you cant tell if AM or PM. also, MM does not work

Comment: You should add a `CultureInfo` in ParseExact, as this code will currently fail on systems with a non-english default culture.

Comment: Even on english systems I am pretty confident in saying that a missing "AM/PM" hints strongly towards 24-Hour format, even if the examples do not contain one with hour > 12.

Comment: @Fildor: Yes, that should be specified. But on my (german) PC I would get an exception because of the *Thursday* in the input.

Comment: @raznagul tbh, that format is really not the nicest one to be parsed, anyway. So, I'd expect a bunch of hiccups related to culture.